# Create two dimensional view

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
hallPlace: string[] = [];

// I initialize array default data here
for(let i=0; i<160; i++) {
    if(i%5===0) {
        this.hallPlace[i] = 1
    } else {
        this.hallPlace[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to display twenty elements in one row

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let place of hallPlace; let i = index">
        <span>{{place[i]}}</span>
        <br *ngIf="i%20 ===0" >
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it displays only the first element in the array rest elemens are hidden. Is there a better way to display data as container contains row and columns?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You seem be trying to create a two dimensional array. But the code you use to initialize the array produces a simple array, not two dimensional array.

Comment: @NiK648 I want to create view dwo dimentional from one dimentional array

Comment: i think the best aproach is to create a two dimentional array.

hallPlace: string [][] = [][]

Comment: @DanielTorresLaserna It is way to display two dimentional array using ul li?

Comment: yes, i will post a snippet with the idea of it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to iterate through a two dimentional array something like this

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let place of hallPlace; let i = index">
        <li *ngFor="let spot of place; let j = index">
          <span>{{place[i][j]}}</span>
        </li>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: try with a ul > li > div